# Error while creating midp project in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, midp

I want to create a midp (Mobile Information Device Profile) project in netbeans. I follow guide as given at its official website . When I run project it gives error as follows...

> Failed to connect to device 4! Reason: Emulator 4 terminated while
>   waiting for it to register! D:\java mobile
>   projects\MyHelloMIDlet\nbproject\build-impl.xml:782: Execution failed
>   with error code 1. BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

I have configure Netbeans properly as given at this link  :

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/quickstart.html#reqs